# Packing stuff in a line - Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 5 labels as follows:

Pack them in order, making sure that the one in the middle is configured to expand:
    import Tkinter as tk

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.one = tk.Label(text="1", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.two = tk.Label(text="2", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.three = tk.Label(text="3", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.four = tk.Label(text="4", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.five = tk.Label(text="5", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")

        self.one.pack(side="left")
        self.two.pack(side="left")
        self.three.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.four.pack(side="left")
        self.five.pack(side="left")
```

And want them to display as follows:

`1 2          3         4 5`

Which means that they must be in a line and `self.reStarter` must be centered between 2 and 5 (i.e. self.mineCount and self.flagTrackerI).

With the current code I get 1 and 2 beside each other in the top left corner and 3 a bit away (not probably in the center) as it pushes 4 5 in the second line as shown below

```
1 2           3
                        4 5
```

Can somebody help me get this working or suggest where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to replace your original code by the answer's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack them in order, making sure that the one in the middle is configured to expand:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.one = tk.Label(text="1", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.two = tk.Label(text="2", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.three = tk.Label(text="3", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.four = tk.Label(text="4", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        self.five = tk.Label(text="5", borderwidth=1, relief="raised")

        self.one.pack(side="left")
        self.two.pack(side="left")
        self.three.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.four.pack(side="left")
        self.five.pack(side="left")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("200x100")
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thnx very much! really appreciated'

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to pack the labels into [grid](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm), giving it column you want as needed to be on the left side / right side / center.

Comment: You could make a better answer by speaking about columnconfigure and sticky. Also say that pack and grid are two possible methods that shouldn't be mixed.

Comment: And add an empty column in between if you want some space there, or the use grid's columnspan to span more than one column.  Most widgets, like labels, will also take a width option, so you could use that as well.